# Can you set up a Patreon if part of your work were made by other people?

Tags: fraud, finance

I don't see anything in the community guidelines that forces you to produce work that's 100% produced by you in order to get money from Patreon. So is this ok, and can you even finance your private company using Patreon?

Comment: Pretty sure that some of the video game folks on Patreon are doing exactly this.